# retrieve data from access database

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to retrieve a path of an image from access

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ImageName AS 'ImageName', ImagePath AS 'Path' FROM [AImages]  WHERE ID='" + _ID + "'";
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
myAdapter.Fill(myTable);
```

but in last line an error occurred like this:    Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Please, please, please use a parameterized query and *don't* build up the sql with string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the way you pass an ID, maybe you can try this instead:

```
// note the ID=?
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ImageName AS 'ImageName', ImagePath AS 'Path' FROM [AImages]  WHERE ID=?";
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// now a parameter
var pId = new OleDbParameter {Value = _ID};
myCommand.Parameters.Add(pId);
```

I hope this helps.